# Consulta Mysql com PHP traz resultados duplicados

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando criar um código em php para montar um ranking, consegui fazer os dados aparecerem, o problema é que está duplicando os resultados.

```
$rank = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_quizzes ORDER BY pass_score_point DESC") or die(mysql_error());

    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rank)){
        $i++;

$rank2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE not UserName='admin' ORDER BY UserName DESC") or die(mysql_error());
    $i2 = 0;
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rank2)){
        $i2++;

$result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(pass_score_point) AS pass_score_point FROM user_quizzes' ); 
$row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row3['pass_score_point'];       


?>


        <div class="topo">
         <?php echo $row2['UserName']; ?> com <?php echo $row3['pass_score_point']; ?> pontos de acertos! 
        </div>
```

Comment: Posta o restante do código onde você busca os dados...

Comment: Desculpa eu não vi, que não tinha ido, pronto

Comment: coloque sua query do banco de dados

Comment: retire seus dados de conexão se não vao entrar no seu db

Comment: ja tirei, obrigado

Comment: Esses whiles ai estão estranhos são todos encadeados? use o botão `{ } ` para formatar o código.

Comment: aco melhor vc trocar a sua senha a favor so por questoes de seguranca

Answer (score 1):

Na sua consulta:
[SELECT SUM(pass_score_point) AS pass_score_point FROM user_quizzes]
você tem que agrupar por alguma coluna com GROUP BY
Ex.:
SELECT userName, SUM(pass_score_point) AS pass_score_point FROM user_quizzes Group By userName

Não sei por que campo você terá que agrupar mas funções de agregação como SUM() tem que ter o group by.

Segue abaixo a sintaxe do GROUP By:

SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name;

Comment: Não adiantou, eu deveria tirar a assoc ? Pq da erro na linha debaixo

Comment: passa a estrutura da tabela user_quizzes e a consulta que você executou.

Answer (score 0):

tente fazer isso na sua query

```
$rank2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID='".$row['user_id']."' LIMIT 0,1") or die(mysql_error());
```

e veja se o problema de duplicata foi resolvido

Comment: Tá, mas pensando que serão vários alunos, com resultados diferentes..

Comment: você pode no seu exemplo [link]http://www.rfsys.com.br/prova/rank.php colocar mais alunos para que possa ver se esta repetindo  na sua query, você já verificou se no seu  db está mais de um resultado igual ?

Comment: @RicardoGoncalves muito  provavel você está com algo  repetido nesse seu banco de dados,  pois você na sua query faz com que seja trago todos os registros do banco.

Comment: começou aparecer duplicado, depois que eu fiz o comando de soma dos campos, porque no caso ali, ele respondeu duas provas, uma tirou 9 e a outra 7, caso eu tire o campo de soma, aparece o resultado correto.. mesmo que respondeu provas diferentes...

Comment: @RicardoGoncalves estou verificando aqui

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: to tentando  recriar seu codigo aqui mas  não  ta dando  muito certo, está mal formatado, se quiser me enviar esta parte no meu email  contato@fottic.com para que eu consiga  reproduzir aqui, e ao invez de fazer a soma no  mysql  já tentou  no php ?

Comment: Não, como seria a soma no php?

Comment: certo quais os campos e de quais bancos você deseja somar exemplo eu vejo que você quer fazer a soma do pass_score_point do user quizzer mais qual outro campo você deseja soma-lo

Comment: eu mudei a resposta acima teste-a e veja se dará algum resultado

Comment: Nop, continua a mesma coisa